# Remove comma and change word order

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I have a text file in which every line has this format (the number of words before and after the comma may vary, but it is at least one before and one after it):

```
some words,a few other words
```

And I want its content to be displayed on the terminal like this:

```
a few other words some words
```

How can I do this? The only thing I can think of is using the `tr` command to replace the comma with a space, but I have no clue as to how to change the order of the words.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The shell is intended to facilitate running other programs, not processing data. I would pick a different language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using awk, you could use the `-F` option:

```
$>cat f
some words,a few other words
foo,bar
$>awk -F',' '{print $2,$1}' f
a few other words some words
bar foo
```

An other option is using sed:

```
$>sed 's/\(.*\),\(.*\)/\2 \1/g' f
a few other words some words
bar foo
```

Finally, with a while loop:

```
$>while IFS=, read part1 part2; do echo "$part2" "$part1";done <f
a few other words some words
bar foo
```

You have to be sure that there is only 1 comma on each line though…

Comment: I just tryed the first option and it worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
cat yourfile.txt|sed -E 's/(.*),(.*)/\2 \1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what AWK is for (when defining field separator to be the comma):

```
$ echo "some words,a few other words" | awk -F, '{ print $2,$1 }'
a few other words some words
```

**Edit:**
Just noticed that @fredtantini had the same (accepted) solution. I leave it here as it shows the solution in a more concise (clear) way (i.e., it doesn't utilise an external file).